# Microsoft service bus - Receive messages from Bus with OnMessage() method

Tags: c#, .net, azureservicebus

My application has to receive a message every time new message is posted. So I'm using `OnMessage()` method as mentioned in Microsoft documentation.

When new messages are posted the `OnMessage()` method does not seem to be working. To resolve this, I've placed the code into a separate task with infinite loop. This seems totally wrong.

```
public void ReceiveMessageFromSubscription(string topicName, string subscriptioName)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            SubscriptionClient Client = SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, topicName, subscriptionName);

            Client.OnMessage((message) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var message = brokerMessage.GetBody<MessageDto>();
                    newMessage.AnnounceNewMessage(message);
                    message.Complete();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    message.Abandon();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Whenever there is a message in Subscription the `OnMessage()` method has to be called. Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: `...does not seem to be working...` - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: So you started a new thread, and that thread creates unlimited number of instances of `SubscriptionClient`, as fast as it can, and subscribes each of the `SubscriptionClient`s to `OnMessage`. Don't you run out of memory right after starting this?

Comment: @JohnB ,the OnMessage() method is not calling automatically whenever there is a message in Subscriptionclient

Comment: @GSerg,Presently it's working fine.But I know that this is not the correct way to achieve this and It will cause Memory out of range issues .That's why I'm trying to find a solution without repeating that loop.I've added that loop to check whether it's working or not.Can you please help me

Answer (score 1):

OnMessage API is an asynchronous process that receives messages in an event-driven message pump. It doesn't stop receiving until you either dispose the client or the code that is running it is terminated. The code above is wrong. You should **not** instantiate a subscription client in a tight loop and register your callback each time. What you *should* be doing is creating your client, registering a callback with a desired concurrency, and hold on to that client until you no longer need to receive messages.

Remember, it's a message **pump** that has to run all the time. Official documentation is a bit dry, perhaps this [post](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/azure-service-bus-onmessage-api) will help.

In addition to that, I would strongly recommend not to use the legacy client [WindowsAzure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/) which you're using. Instead, prefer the new [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/) client.